# Magento 2 - how to re-install missing foreign-key constraints?

Tags: magento2, database, third-party-module, foreign-key-constraint

I am using a third party extension.
I noticed that a constraint is missing by comparing with a fresh installation. This causes a bug when deleting an item of the extension.

Is there a command which is able to install missing constraints?

I've tried this:

1. delete entry of module from table `setup_modules`
2. 

```
php -f bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
php -f bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

but none of these commands re-installed the missing constraint.

---

The only way I've found is deleting the table and the extension entry from the table `setup_module` and executing `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, but this is too radical since I have to re-add the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed this SQL which can be used to compare a fresh magento 2 with another database, to find missing constraints. You will have to manually create them though. But im sure there is also a way to develop a script which does this.

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'name_of_fresh_database'
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME NOT IN (
    SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'name_of_other_database'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no automated way to do that in Magento.

**Option 1**

Run the `setup:*` for a fresh table and then migrate the existing data into the new tables

**Option 2**

If you know which foreign key constraints are missing you could manually add them with `ALTER TABLE <YOUR TABLE> ADD CONSTRAINT ...`

Comment: I also think so. I developed a little SQL to find missing constraints by comparing with a fresh database